# Asynchronous libmemcached usage

Tags: linux, memcached, libmemcache, libmemcached

I want to use the method memcached_mget_execute() to retrieve values from a memcached server. 
But I get the following error message:
"ACTION NOT SUPPORTED, ASCII protocol is not supported for memcached_mget_execute_by_key() -> libmemcached/get.cc:437"

Also someone please provide me some good resources for using libmemcached **strictly in C**

Answer (score 1):

you should change ASCII protocol to BINARY protocol and try again.